# Python reporting abspath as directly within CWD rather than the actual correct directory

Tags: python, os.path

I am attempting to code a small script to sort music tracks for me.
I'm running into a problem where the script looks for the file in the wrong place.

The user defines the directory to look for files in via input, and validates the directory exists. It then filters out anything that isn't an mp3 file. It reports the number of unsorted files found correctly. This is all working fine.

My .py file is located in Desktop\Programming\Music
The directory with files I'm attempting to sort is located in Desktop\Programming\Music\Test_Music

**The script is reporting the absolute path of the file as directly within my CWD, rather than within the real directory Test_Music.**

INPUT:

```
.
.
.

#list all files in parent directory
tracks = os.listdir(parent_dir)

#Filtering only the files, not folders.
tracks = [f for f in tracks if os.path.isfile(parent_dir+'/'+f)] 

#report how many tracks were found
print("Found " + str(len(tracks)) + " unsorted files in parent directory.")

#troubleshoot, report the current working directory
print("CWD: " + str(Path.cwd()))

#troubleshoot, print the absolute path of each track
for track in tracks:
    #convert track string to a windowspath object type
    p_track = Path(track)

    #print the absolute path of each track
    print(os.path.abspath(p_track))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Found 11 unsorted files in parent directory.
CWD: C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Sanctuary 1.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Soft.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Something Bigger, Something Brigh.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Something New 1.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Something.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Somewhere in October.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Stars (feat. Eva Maria).mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Stav.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Stay 1.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Stupid Love.mp3
C:\Users\im\Desktop\Programming\01 Sugar Haze 2.mp3
```

**This is incorrect. All tracks are located in Desktop\Programming\Music\Test_Music. So where did I go wrong?**

I've tried defining the path as, for example, `(os.path.dirname(str(track))) + (os.path.basename(str(track)))` but `(os.path.dirname(str(track))` shows up completely empty, as does os.path.dirname(Path(track)). I'm new to coding so I'm likely missing something obvious.

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns bare filenames.  You have to join them to the directory name to have them actually refer to the files in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
tracks = [f for f in tracks if os.path.isfile(parent_dir+'/'+f)]
```

You check if `parent_dir+'/'+f` is a file and then put `f` in the list. A simple fix should be

```py
tracks = [parent_dir+'/'+f for f in tracks if os.path.isfile(parent_dir+'/'+f)]
```

Personally, I prefer to use `Path` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (which you use in some places as well).

Then you could do something like:

```py
parent_path = Path(parent_dir).absolute()
tracks = [entry for entry in parent_path.iterdir() if entry.is_file()]
```

Comment: This worked! You're absolutely right that I wasn't careful in distinguishing between the file name being added to the array versus the actual absolute path of the file. I caught this same breed of error one more time further along in the code, too. Thank you!